# GCP cloud operation : MQL query -- filter values greater than a number

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

So we are trying to set up an MQL for alerting on a custom metrics ( that we are ingesting in cloud operation through monitoring API). I am struggling to find a good way to filter results based on the metric value. Below is the MQL and corresponding metrics.
I am trying to filter all values greater than say 100000. How can I do that ?

[image: MQL screenshot]

Comment: Did you check the [MQL Reference Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#lexical-elements)? [Here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples) you can find useful MQL examples. Please let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have the same question. And no, it's not in the examples!

Answer (score 0):

It is work to me:

```
 | filter ( gt( cast_units(value_counts_mean,'By/s'), 1000 ))
```